# Restier - Entity Framework - LOADMEMORYQUERY

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, odata, restier

I'm working with [Restier](https://github.com/OData/RESTier) which sits on top of the Entity Framework and Web API. When I make a call with a $top operator:

```
/entitySet?$top=10
```

The resultant query captured by the [interceptor debugger](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/01/02/entity-framework-query-visual-studio.aspx) is as follows:

```
LOADMEMORYQUERY 'SELECT * FROM [entitySet] /*EntityFramework Load MemoryQuery*/';MEMORYQUERY [entitySet] 'SELECT * FROM [entitySet] LIMIT 10'
```

Which ends up running the first query against the DB of:

```
SELECT * FROM [entitySet]
```

How do I avoid the LOADMEMORYQUERY call? It is a very large dataset and I would prefer to only pull from the DB what I need.

Comment: What providers are you using? as in Microsoft.Restier.Providers.InMemory

Comment: CData.Salesforce 18.0.6817 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/CData.Salesforce/

Comment: Can you try adding a $skip=0. the LIMIT should look like 
LIMIT <rows to skip><row to return>

Answer (score -2):

It's radical answer, but if you want to optimize performance, it would be better to avoid using OData and most probably EF

Comment: Downvoted as this is just an opinion and not really a helpful answer for the exact question